# React form onSubmit is not working and input not allow to use white spaces

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

GitHub Issue: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4290#issuecomment-380521431

I found strength thing:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import FieldGroup from "./FieldGroup";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
    class UserUpdateForm extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleUserUpdate = this.handleUserUpdate.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeNickname = this.handleChangeNickname.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          name: this.props.current_user.name,
          nickname: this.props.current_user.nickname
        };
      }

      handleChangeName(event) {
        this.setState({
          name: event.target.value
        });
      }
      handleChangeNickname(event) {
        this.setState({
          nickname: event.target.value
        });
      }

      handleUserUpdate(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const url = event.target.action;
        console.log(url);
        return false;
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <Form
            onSubmit={this.handleUserUpdate}
            action={this.props.action}
            method="patch"
            id={this.props.id}
          >
            <FieldGroup
              role="form"
              id={`${this.props.id}Name`}
              type="text"
              label="User Name"
              placeholder="Enter User Name"
              onChange={this.handleChangeName}
              value={this.state.name}
            />
            <FieldGroup
              role="form"
              id={`${this.props.id}Nickname`}
              type="text"
              label="User Nickname"
              placeholder="Enter User Nickname"
              onChange={this.handleChangeNickname}
              value={this.state.nickname}
            />
            <Button className="btn btn-primary btn-large centerButton" type="submit">Send</Button>
          </Form>
        );
      }
    }

    export default connect(state => ({
      current_user: state.current_user
    }))(UserUpdateForm);
```

The Sign In/Sign Up form work, but UserUpdate not. Actually, `onSubmit` doesn't work. Also whitespaces skipped. I don't see `console.log(url)` or error.

I think, problem is in the `<Navbar>` Component of `react-bootstrap`, because, when i wrote my own `<Modal>` and inserted it to this `<Navbar>`, the problem wasn't solved. If I move `<form>` from `<Navbar>` all work.

App: https://on-money.herokuapp.com

Git: https://github.com/yashka713/on_money_front/blob/deploy/src/forms/UserUpdateForm.js

login: `onioni@example.com`

password: `password`

You should click on `User profile` and then click to `FontAwesome Icon`.
Thx :)

Comment: If you are adding the method and action then why are you preventing default in the functioncall ?

Comment: @YashThakur because I don't want to refresh page. I just want to see `console.log` and be sure, that `onSubmit` work.

Answer (score 1):

I found something, which looks like solution: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3105

And I want to cry.

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO. Please put the relevant information here, in your answer.